# Matlab .m file is supposed to be a function but doesn't

Tags: matlab

I am using Neuralynx files for my works.
When I want to use a function (that works properly on another computer) like Nlx2MatSpike and I call it with it's needed arguments, it says:

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT Nlx2MatSpike as a function:
>   /home/Me/MatlabLibs/Neurolynx_files/Nlx2MatSpike.m

and also before this kind of error appear, Another error was occured:

> Undefined function "Nlx2MatSpike" for input arguments of type 'char'

Do you have any ideas about solving this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the file is just a script, not a function, just make it a function?

Comment: its a function and it is working on other computers. but it takes it as a script!

Comment: You haven't accidentally edited it in the process of moving it from the other computer? Or mixed up two different versions of the file which are in different locations on your hard drive?  (You can try `which <filename> -all`  to check if there are multiple copies on your path).

Comment: Is `/home/Me/MatlabLibs/Neurolynx_files` part of the Matlab-search-path?

Answer (score 0):

A function in MATLAB is a `.m` file which is declared as a function. Probably this declaration is missing.

Make sure the file starts with a line like

```
function [retval1, retval2, retval3] = Nlx2MatSpike(param1, param2, param3)
```

or something alike.

Depends on how you want to use the function and how it is built.

Comment: Not Wokring! it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are Mac and Linux versions of the Neuralynx file readers available at Ueli Rutishauser's website: http://www.urut.ch/new/serendipity/index.php?/pages/nlxtomatlab.html